# AngularJS - Possible to ng-show/ng-hide a modal window?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to keep the state of my bootstrap.ui (OR ngdialog!!) modal window when it is closed.  Any idea how I might ng-show/ng-hide a modal window?

Thanks.

Comment: possibly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21578997/how-to-hide-show-same-modal-instance-with-angularjs?

Comment: No, the "show" option doesn't exist for bootstrap.ui modal.  I don't know what that guy was talking about.  docs - https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/  - i actually wish someone would downvote him and add a comment, I can't as I've not enough rep.

Comment: well you can always  use display or visibility with pure css...

Comment: Yeah I'd thought of that, just hoped there was another way!  Thanks.

Comment: you can add a hide or show class to the .modal-dialog  level and toggle it

Comment: its very easy and serves your purpose I think if you want to keep the data only hide it... especially if you say that ui-bootstrap does not support hide... you can always wrap the modal with your own directive and do its manually with bootstrap

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look this example:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-init="showModal=false">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="showModal = !showModal">
            Launch demo modal
        </button>
        <div class="modal fade in" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block;" ng-show="showModal">  
            <div class="modal-dialog">    
                <div class="modal-content">   
                    MODAL   
                    <div class="modal-footer">        
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="showModal=false">Ok</button>     
                    </div>    
                </div>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this good practise to have the modal HTML in the same HTML as your main page?  I also have a controller for my modal, so the ng-model will have to be shared via my service.  Because of this structure, I have a HTML file dedicated to my modal, so my issue would be - how do I ng-show/ng-hide an entire template?

Comment: If the modal is simple can be in code main. This modal is used by other component?

Comment: Thanks for your help, this works pretty well.  It's not as snappy as I'd like it but it's the only solution I've managed to get to work!