# Why do Chrome and Firefox retry 204 requests when they are in the static DOM?

Tags: html, google-chrome, http, firefox, dom

We're currently designing a site that has some tracking pixels hard coded into the DOM. One of the pixels returns with a 204 response code(as it should), but Chrome and Firefox make the request twice.

If the request is made asynchronously, there is only one request.

Is there are a reason why a browser would retry a request with a 204 no content response, is this a valid behavior?

to repro:

```html
<html>
   <body>
     <img src="some/source/url.gif" />
    </body>
</html>
```

and then have your webserver respond to the src url with a 204 response code.

Comment: no this is not normal , would you show your code please ?

Comment: As a note: [`MDN: [...]The HTML <image> element was an experimental element designed to display pictures. It never was implemented and the standard <img> element must be used. [...]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/image)

Comment: Perhaps a dupe of:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25819736/why-do-browsers-inefficiently-make-2-requests-here/25871528

Comment: sorry updated the code, not actually using the image tag, using standard img