# Angular2: Show placeholder image if img src is not valid

Tags: javascript, angular

**Goal**: Load an image with a dynamic source.  If no image is found, then load a placeholder image instead.

This should demonstrate what I'm trying to do, but I don't know how to conditionally set `validImage` based on whether the first `img` `src` is valid.

```
<img *ngif="validImage" class="thumbnail-image" src="./app/assets/images/{{image.ID}}.jpg" alt="...">
<img *ngif="!validImage" class="thumbnail-image" src="./app/assets/images/placeholder.jpg" alt="...">
```

`validImage` should be `true` if `src="./app/assets/images/{{image.ID}}.jpg"` returns an image.  Otherwise it would return `false` and only the second `img` tag should show.

There are obvious work arounds like storing a list of all valid image sources, but I'm thinking there is a better way to accomplish this.

Any suggestions on the best way to implement this in Angular2 would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 170, accepted):

The best way to handle broken image links is the use the `onError` event for the `<img>` tag:

```
<img  class="thumbnail-image" src="./app/assets/images/{{image.ID}}.jpg"
      onerror="this.src='./app/assets/images/placeholder.jpg';"  alt="..." />
```

Comment: One thing to note, make sure your placeholder image is always in that location or you could get an endless loop I think :)

Comment: Why Does it create goes into a loop?

Comment: Is there a way to suppress the 404 error that gets logged as well?

Comment: Amazing !!, But didn't understand why to use `this.src`? it should work without this too but not working

Comment: `[src]="imagePath"` if you are setting the entire path.

Comment: @JanR It is working but why i am getting error in console.log() with 404 ?

Comment: the onError attribute could remove itself to avoid a loop (and maybe add an alt attribute). You could also use a data URI

Comment: icanuse, https://www.caniuse.com/mdn-html_elements_img_onerror, lists onerror as "This feature is deprecated/obsolete and should not be used." As well as this is not supported for IE11 (for those who have to give commercial support)

Answer (score 47):

```
<img [src]="pic" (error)="setDefaultPic()">
```

And somewhere in your component class:

```
setDefaultPic() {
  this.pic = "assets/images/my-image.png";
}
```

Comment: Better than the accepted answer. It allows you to do much more things on error (remove the img tag and display a text maybe...), not only changing the img src.

Answer (score 32):

I ran into a similar need. I wanted to default to a 1X1 transparent pixel if an img url was null or returned an error (404 etc).

```
import { Directive, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: 'img[src]',
    host: {
        '[src]': 'checkPath(src)',
        '(error)': 'onError()'
    }
})
export class DefaultImage { 
    @Input() src: string;
    public defaultImg: string = '{YOUR_DEFAULT_IMG}';
    public onError() {
        this.src = this.defaultImg;
    }
    public checkPath(src) {
        return src ? src : this.defaultImg;
    }
}
```

Markup

```
<img [src]="{DESIRED_IMAGE_SOURCE}" />
```

Comment: Excellent solution, because src can be null and will not throw an 404 error in that case.

Comment: Can you show an example of template using your solution ?

Comment: I don't think `onError()` would actually do anything in this case? It just returns a string...

Comment: the `onError` part needs to be changed to `this.src = this.defaultImg;`

Answer (score 19):

The following approach also works if you want to handle the error in you class:

In your template:

```
<img [src]='varWithPath' (error) ="onImgError($event)">
```

In your class:

```
onImgError(event) { 
    event.target.src = 'assets/path_to_your_placeholder_image.jpg';
}
```

Comment: I prefer this to the selected answer, I find it cleaner. Thx!

Answer (score 4):

I've created a custom component that uses a placeholder image if the image is still not loaded or if an error occurs when loading it:

*img.component.ts:*

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-img',
    templateUrl: 'img.component.html',
})
export class ImgComponent implements OnChanges {
    @Input() 
    public src: string;
    @Input() 
    public default: string;
    @Input() 
    public alt: string;
    public cached = false;
    public loaded = false;
    public error = false;

    private lastSrc: string;

    constructor() { }

    public ngOnChanges() {
        if (this.src !== this.lastSrc) {
            this.lastSrc = this.src;
            this.loaded = false;
            this.error = false;
            this.cached = this.isCached(this.src);
        }

        if (!this.src) {
            this.error = true;
        }
    }

    public onLoad() {
        this.loaded = true;
    }

    public onError() {
        this.error = true;
    }

    private isCached(url: string): boolean {
        if (!url) {
            return false;
        }

        let image = new Image();
        image.src = url;
        let complete = image.complete;

        // console.log('isCached', complete, url);

        return complete;
    }
}
```

*img.component.html:*

```
<ng-container *ngIf="!cached">
    <img 
        *ngIf="!error" 
        [hidden]="!loaded"
        [src]="src" 
        [alt]="alt" 
        (load)="onLoad()" 
        (error)="onError()"
    >
    <img 
        *ngIf="default && (error || !loaded)" 
        [src]="default" 
        [alt]="alt"
    >
</ng-container>

<ng-container *ngIf="cached">
    <img 
        *ngIf="!error" 
        [src]="src" 
        [alt]="alt" 
        (error)="onError()"
    >
    <img 
        *ngIf="default && error" 
        [src]="default" 
        [alt]="alt"
    >
</ng-container>
```

Then you can use it like:

```
<my-img [src]="src" [alt]="alt" [default]="DEFAULT_IMAGE"></my-img>
```

*PS: I verify beforehand if the image is cached to avoid the image blinking (normally when a component that has the image inside is re-rendered) between the placeholder and the image (if it is cached, I show the image even before the loaded flag be set to true). You can uncomment the log in the `isCached` function to see if your images are cached or not.*

Comment: Am I right that in your solution you cache every image component separately and thus spend extra memory on every same image occurance on the page (example: table where several cells show the same image, other cells a different one)? I'm almost sure browser default caching of images is much more effective in this case.

Comment: @ArseniiFomin The cache is not separate. It's only one cache per image (unless you inlude some parameter to bypass that, but that also happens when you use `img` `src`). If the cache was different for the same image, it would always return `false` when `isCached()` is called. You can make the test of loading an image in an `img` tag and after call `new Image()` passing the same `src` and see that `isCached()` returns `true` synchronously (because it uses the same cache). You can also inspect in your browser inspector to see the network calls.

Comment: @ArseniiFomin Just to complement what I said earlier, the javascript native Image uses the browser default caching: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/10240297/4850646](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10240297/4850646)

Comment: so all caching is done internally in Image class implementation?

Comment: The javascript `Image` uses the browser cache. From the [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image): The `Image()` constructor creates a new `HTMLImageElement` instance. It is functionally equivalent to `document.createElement('img')`.

Comment: what if I want to pass down css class names to the img element?

Comment: @devmiles.com If it will be in a code that you have control and can change (like a css file that you can modify), I advise to include the class in the `my-img` element and make the css rule like `my-img.my-class img { ... }`. If you really need to include the class in the `img` element, then you could change the component to have a `@Input()` that receives the class and pass it to the 4 `img` elements in the html template (like `<img [class]="myInput" ... >`).

Answer (score 1):

```
<img class="thumbnail-image" src="getImage()" alt="...">

getImage():string{  //I don't know how would you handle your situation here. But you can think of it.

  if (this.validImage) // I don't know how would you manage validImage here.
  {
     return this.validImagePath;
  }

   return this.placeholderImagePath;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
src="validImage ? validImageUrl : placeHolderImgUrl"
```

Comment: Doesn't work if the result comes back as a bad request. Must use @JanR's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I Just did this :

In my HTML FILE wrote this

```
<div 
   (click)="getInfo(results[movie].id)"
   *ngFor="let movie of (results | key:'10')" 
    class="card" style="margin-top:7%;">
 <img [src]="getImage(results[movie])" alt="" class="card-img-top pointer"></div>
```

I called a function that is in my component.ts and pass the object wheres my url as a parameter

```
getImage(result){
if(result.poster_path){
  return this.imageURL+(result.poster_path);
}else return "./assets/noFound.jpg"
```

Heres my function , first I verify if the object image url is different from null if is true then I return the image url else i return my default "noFound" image that is in my app assets.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use property binding and OR operator to do this without generating a 404 error in the console. Just make sure to provide the exact location for the placeholder image.

```
<img class="thumbnail-image" [src]="validImage || '/assets/images/placeholder.jpg'" alt="...">
```

In here, the **validImage** property should provide the dynamic image. If it's not available, it uses the placeholder image.