# Don't display an image that's not found in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a carousel which loads a bunch of images, but there's a possibility the image path is broken and the image can't be found.

If that's the case it currently causes an empty  tag to be added, which adds an empty box and it's not intended to be there. Here's my code:

```
    <div class="gallery-img" gallerize>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let p of dynamicPaths">
          <img src="{{p}}">
      </ng-container>
    </div>
```

How do I prevent the image tag to be added at all if there's no image for that path?

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36026428/angular2-show-placeholder-image-if-img-src-is-not-valid

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2: Show placeholder image if img src is not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36026428/angular2-show-placeholder-image-if-img-src-is-not-valid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to discovering the `(error)` event I managed to think of a simple solution by tracking the index and splicing out the path. That way, the image tag simply won't be added.

```
<div class="gallery-img" gallerize>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let p of dynamicPaths; let i = index">
      <img src="{{p}}" (error)="dynamicPaths.splice(i, 1)">
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using error event and hidden html data binding you should be able to achieve this easily.

```
<img #myImage [hidden]="myImage.isBugged" (error)="myImage.isBugged = true" src="{{p}}">
```

Comment: Since I'm looping through several paths, wouldn't it  break the binding?

Comment: It should not !

Comment: @SimeonNakov Please, accept the answer If it fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Angular 2 - Check if image url is valid or broken

Refer This also:
[Angular 2 - Check if image url is valid or broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36429903/angular-2-check-if-image-url-is-valid-or-broken)