# Invoke Java Servlet logic without directing to new page

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp, servlets

From my webpage I am making a GET request to a servlet via a button. My servlet reads from a webcam and saves an image file (saved to 'img/frame.jpg'). My webpage then includes a script to read from this file every second, so it's updated on the webpage.

Webpage:

```
<html>
<body>
    <img id='feed' src="img/frame.jpg" />
    <form method="GET"
        action="startCCTV.do">
        <br><br>
        <center>
            <input type="SUBMIT"? value='Start'/>
        </center>
    </form>
    <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js'></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

JavaScript (**updated since the question was answered**):

```
window.setInterval(function updateFrame() {
    invokeServlet();
},  1000);

// Preload images.
function refreshImage() {
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = "img/frame.jpg?" + new Date().getTime();
    image.onload = function() {
        // Image exists and is loaded.
        $("#feed").attr('src', "img/frame.jpg?" + new Date().getTime());
    }    
}

// Send a GET request to the Servlet, to write a new image from the webcam.
function invokeServlet() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4) {
            refreshImage();
        }   
    };

    xhttp.open("GET", "startCCTV.do", true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

I did have an infinite loop in my servlet to continuously write a new image, so the image would be updated on the webpage. However, it doesn't seem like a good way to do it (the image refreshed every 3 or 4 seconds and sometimes didn't appear at all). I think the best way would be to have my GET request in a loop in my `updateFrame()` function, and have the servlet write one image per request.

However, I don't know how to make this request in my Javascript, without being redirected to the servlet response once the servlet has completed it's writing process.

How can I make intermittent requests to my servlet without being redirected to a new page (i.e. just have the image refreshed on my page)?

Comment: What about doing Ajax Call?

Comment: @Yohannes Would you be able to give me an example please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested, the solution was to use an AJAX call. I implemented this as follows :

```
// Send a GET request to the Servlet, to write a new image from the webcam.
function invokeServlet() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4) {
            refreshImage();
        }   
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "startCCTV.do", true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

I called this `invokeServlet` method from my `setInterval` method. I've updated the JavaScript in the question to include this.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid flicker, missing image while loading, you could preload the new image and display when load completed.
How to do that is available in other [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240110/how-do-you-cache-an-image-in-javascript).

Comment: I have now shown my full JavaScript code - I'm checking the images are loaded in my `refreshImage()` method via `image.onload`. However, the image does still disappear sometimes...do you know what might be wrong? Thanks!

Comment: In your code, new Date().getTime() has a different value when load completes later. 
You could save the URL to load in a variable and display the same that was loaded.