# store images in angular local environment without use of web api

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-material

> is there any option available in angular that allows to store images or pdf in angular local environment.

```
as i tried to implement but i haven't got success in that.
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: does this solve your question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240110/how-do-you-cache-an-image-in-javascript

Comment: no @AlexYu because after one or two day i have to access this same thing than that's not possible in that

Comment: You can store files inside the `assets` folder. Please provide examples of how you try to do that.

Comment: @DmitryGrinko as i don't have any backup code but i tried this same but haven't able to store

Comment: Does this answer the question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183180/how-to-save-an-image-to-localstorage-and-display-it-on-the-next-page

Comment: Storing data in this size as base64 data url is too much big for a storage and for sure will lead with high performance issues in case if files that are stored became much...  Best thing to do is to serve those files from a server u create or perhaps you could use firebase as it gives a good free storage space and if u got your own backend and serve files from it would be much better... and after that you would provide a caching service which could serve the files fast and act for future work as data is on device and not being served each time from server.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you don't have write file access in browser for security reasons.
but you can choose one of these approaches.

1- local storage gives you 5M space so you can convert your image to base64 string then store it their.

2- or you need to use cordova or capacitor plugin to do that if you work with ionic

Comment: but i want to store that image in my project folder

Comment: @ManthanMachhi you must pick the second approach.

Comment: yes that's good but right now i'm working in angular project