# How to cache images on site load with React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a dashboard, and on load it hits a database and gets a bunch of URLs, which are then rendered into IMG elements, like so:

```
<img src={Item.imageURL}/>
```

The issue is, that every time I open another route and then go back to the one with the images, the `img` components are being reloaded and the images are downloaded again. It results in icons visibly being loaded from top to bottom every time.

Is there a way to load these images the moment the URLs are retrieved from the database and then keep them in the cache, so that they will load immediately? Like I'd do `import image from "./image.png"` with local images.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you cache an image in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240110/how-do-you-cache-an-image-in-javascript)

Comment: Hey, unfortunately, it doesn't, because as I've said, the images are re-downloaded every time the route is rendered, so the cache doesn't seem to be working.